# Admin panel for inputting data for Parse.com?

Tags: parse-platform

If an app that uses Parse needs a web-based data admin system, what's the best way to go?

I know Parse.com already offers a data browser, but its main use case isn't for someone to mass enter data or perform admin functions. I know I can make one from scratch with the libraries found here [on the Parse API Libraries page](https://parse.com/docs/api_libraries), but I was just wondering if there was a standard or most used way to use 3rd party admin panels.

Answer (score 1):

Given that there is no "standard data admin", other than perhaps letting them edit all fields on all objects (which is provided by the data browser), I wouldn't expect to find some 3rd party admin panel.

What you do and don't expose in an admin interface often varies from product to product, some fields might be there only to support easier searching and be read-only (or hidden) even in admin screens.

Unfortunately that means you need to roll your own admin screens using whichever SDK works best for you.

Be aware that (last I checked) the JavaScript SDK only works for Internet Explorer if your pages are hosted on SSL (https), due to a quirk in IE. If you want to support IE you might want to use Parse's Cloud Hosting.